# ¿Cómo sumar tiempo de cada usuario en una sola tabla, en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, datetime, mssql

Estoy tratando de sumar el tiempo de cada usuario pero solo consigo sumar el tiempo total de todos. Estuve pensando que con un **GROUP BY** pero no consigo sumarlos.
Mi Query es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE  @TalkTime TABLE (
    payroll_id VARCHAR(255),
    talkTime TIME(4)
)
INSERT INTO @TalkTime
    ([payroll_id],[talkTime])
VALUES
    ('1','0:45:00'),
    ('2','4:19:00'),
    ('1','4:21:00'),
    ('2','5:52:00'),
    ('1','4:59:00'),
    ('2','6:06:00'),
    ('1','5:03:00'),
    ('2','5:51:00'),
    ('1','5:18:00')
;
DECLARE @hours INT
DECLARE @mins INT
DECLARE @secs INT

SELECT @hours = SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, '0:00:00', talktime)) +
((SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, '0:00:00', talktime)) - (SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, '0:00:00', talktime)) *60)) / 60)
FROM @TalkTime

SELECT @mins = (SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', talktime)) - (@hours*60*60))/60
FROM @TalkTime

SELECT @secs = (SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', talktime))) - ((@hours*60*60) + (@mins*60))
FROM    @TalkTime

SELECT CAST(@hours AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ':' + CAST(@mins AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ':' +  CAST(@secs AS NVARCHAR(2)) AS TOTAL_TIME
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

| TOTAL_TIME |
| --- |
| 42:34:0 |

Y el resultado que espero obtener es el siguiente (es un ejemplo):

| payroll_id | total_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01:40 |
| 2 | 05:20 |

Supongo que con un `GROUP BY` se debe de poder pero no tengo idea de cómo lograrlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente, el problema es que estás usando variables, lo que te limita a trabajar con un valor a la vez. Por lo mismo, es recomendable evitarlas cuando necesitas múltiples datos de un conjunto. Es recomendable evitar el tipo `TIME` porque tiene un límite de 24 horas y luego se reinicia. Lo mejor sería almacenar el tiempo en segundos o minutos según la precisión que requieras.

De cualquier forma, aquí queda una opción para solucionarlo.

```
SELECT payroll_id,
    CONCAT(
        SUM( DATEDIFF( ss, '00:00:00', talkTime)) / 3600, ':',
        RIGHT( 100 + ( SUM( DATEDIFF( ss, '00:00:00', talkTime)) % 3600 / 60), 2), ':',
        RIGHT( 100 + ( SUM( DATEDIFF( ss, '00:00:00', talkTime)) % 3600 % 60), 2))
FROM @TalkTime
GROUP BY payroll_id;
```

Uso Datediff para obtener los segundos y usarlos para sumar. Después divido entre 3600 para obtener las horas y el residuo de la división con módulo (%) para obtener minutos y segundos.